# Replacing strings in a text file using Python adds weird characters

Tags: python, text

I want to replace a text with a path in each line of a text file using Python, but I am getting weird characters (squares) in the path in output file.

Current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

f1 = open('input.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('output.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('test/software', 'C:\Software\api\render\3bit\sim>'))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

In the output text the following in the path is replaced with a square (weird character):

- \a = changed to a square
- \r = changed to a square
- \3 = changed to a square

Is there something wrong with my code or are the above letters reserved for the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python strings support escape codes; a backslash with certain characters is replaced by the code they represent. `\r` is interpreted as the ASCII line-feed character, for example, `\a` is an ASCII BELL, and `\3` is interpreted as the ascii codepoint 3 (in octal numbering). See the Python [string literal documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringliteral).

To disable escape codes being interpreted, use a raw python string by prefixing the string definition with a `r`:

```
r'C:\Software\api\render\3bit\sim>'
```

so your line reads:

```
f2.write(line.replace('test/software', r'C:\Software\api\render\3bit\sim>'))
```

Alternatively, double the backslashes to have them interpreted as a literal backslashes instead:

```
'C:\\Software\\api\\render\\3bit\\sim>'
```

Comment: I don't know much about Windows, but don't forward slashes work too? I could've sworn I read that somewhere.

Comment: @DSM: When working with paths, then yes, forward slashes work too. But this is about modifying text, so we cannot make the assumption that forward slashes will do here.

Answer (score 0):

Your string has backslashes which are read in Python as escape codes. These are when a character preceded by a backslash is changed into a special character. For example, `\n` is a newline. You will need to either escape them (with another backslash) or just use a raw string.

```
r'C:\Software\api\render\3bit\sim>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Before each of your path files, add an "r" character to create a raw string, this might fix the issue. Example:

```
f2.write(line.replace('test/software', r'C:\Software\api\render\3bit\sim>'))
```

Or alternatively, escape your backslashes:

```
f2.write(line.replace('test/software', 'C:\\Software\\api\\render\\3bit\\sim>'))
```